# WCF: Controlling service endpoint name in self-hosted service

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I have a WCF service that's hosted in a Windows service. This service needs to run on one of the user's machines, and it will be accessed by a client application residing on a different machine. The service will be exposed over a BasicHttpBinding. The server will be implemented in C# using .NET 4.0. The client will be implemented using .NET 3.5 (external requirements).

I have done a few tweaks of the service in order to squeeze the entire WSDL into a single file (rather than multiple XSDs). The procedure to do this is outlined e.g. [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/archive/2010/03/16/making-wcf-output-a-single-wsdl-file-for-interop-purposes.aspx) .

I expose the service over a "localhost" endpoint, i.e.:

```
ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(serviceInstance, "http://localhost:8080/...");
```

Its endpoints are exposed as URIs, relative to the above base address.

My problem is that when generating a proxy using VS2010's Add Service Reference, I get a proxy whose default ctor connects to an "http://localhost:8080/..." endpoint. This works fine if the service is hosted on the same machine as the client (during testing, for instance), but obviously fails when the server and client machines are separate: the client machine has no endpoint listening on "http://localhost:8080/...".

The WSDL file contains:

```
<wsdl:service name="MyService">
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IMyService">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/MyService/IMyService" />
```

Granted, I could use a different ctor that receives the real hostname to connect to, but given that I generated the client using the host's real address, I kind of expected the client to automatically connect to this endpoint.

I saw on several forums that instead of using localhost on the server I could use its hostname or IP. However, the host may have multiple hostnames and/or IPs, and the service would not know which to choose.

Is there a way to get the auto-generated proxy to use the "real" server's address (as indicated in the WSDL's URL which was used to create the proxy)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you specify in App.config, <system.serviceModel> section? Maybe you can override the endpoint address, but you can definitely override the meta address.

Comment: I can specify it in app.config, but for that I would have to know in advance the IP / hostname that would be exposed, and I have no way of knowing that (I think): e.g. the hostname might not be exposed outside, and the IP could be translated using NAT.

Comment: Normally, when we deliver a product that uses WCF, we tell the client what to edit in the app.config file. This way nothing is hardcoded and the client can decide what address they want to expose. Also, there's a dynamic way, take a look at this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971842

Comment: Is it a good experience for the user to configure it manually? What happens if the IP address change? The service will break and it'd be hard to guess why. I would rather modify the client code to automatically extract the server's address and use the appropriate client ctor, but I was hoping there was an automatic way.

Comment: Yes, the hotfix does exactly that: whatever address the client sends the request to, it will be used in the WSDL.

Comment: But if I read it correctly it was applicable only to load-balancing scenarios, no? Or is NAT identical to load balancing for this purpose? Also, should this be installed on the server or the client (my server is running .NET 4.0 and the hotfix applies to .NET 3.5, it seems).

Comment: It could be used in any scenario. Whatever address the client uses to contact your server, the WSDL will echo it back. It is useful in load balancers, but other scenarios, too.

Comment: Apparently I don't need the hotfix since my server runs on .NET 4.0. But the hotfix link you posted provided the solution: I have to apply the UseRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress behavior to my service. Thanks!

Comment: So the hotfix is integrated in .NET 4? Nice to know!